# Creating a tree from a txt file in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I'm supposed to implement a tree data structure in Java using the following classes:

```
public class Tree<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
    private TreeNode<T> root;

    public Tree(TreeNode<T> root)
    {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public void findChild(T data) { ... }
    public void findSibling(T data){ ... }
    public void printProgeny() { .. }
    public static Tree<String> createProgeny(String file) { ... }

    ...
}



public class TreeNode<T extends Comparable <T>>
{
    public T data;
    public TreeNode<T> parent;
    public TreeNode<T> leftChild;
    public TreeNode<T> rightSibling;

    ...
}
```

and then test it by reading a txt file that looks like this:

```
Adam Jacob Hannah Sarah
Hannah Esther Abel
Abel David
```

where the first string in a line is the parent of the following strings.
And this is where I'm struggling.

Let's say I split the first line so I'd have an array with [Adam, Jacob, Hannah, Sarah]. How do I create a subtree from this using the given methods?

I think the other methods won't be that hard to implement once I know how to create a tree and set the pointers correctly

Any help is appreciated

EDIT:
The tree would look like this

```
      Adam
  /    |    \
Jacob Hannah Sarah 
      /    \
    Esther  Abel
             |
            David
```

... or after Knuth transform:

```
    Adam
   /
 Jacob
    \
   Hannah
    /    \
 Esther  Sarah
     \
    Abel
    /
  David
```

Comment: I guess `TreeNode` should also have `rightChild` member. What having `rightSibling` means? Is that `this` is the left one? IMHO `TreeNode` should consist of data, leftChild, rightChild and optionally parent members.

Comment: Can you update the question with some ASCII art of what the end-result data structure is? I'm not clear whether "Sarah" is a child of the "Hannah" node or of the "Adam" node.

Comment: @j3ny4 any tree can be represented as a binary tree using only leftChild and rightSibling pointers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_child-right_sibling_binary_tree)

Comment: @WalterWhite Ok. Now I get you. So if your  question is about a specific type of tree (Left-child right-sibling binary tree) please state it clearly. However, the tree you have drew isn't a binary tree (Adam has tree children).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That your methods return `void` is unusual. I can only assume that instead of returning a node, `findChild()` sets a cursor in the object. It's not a style I'm keen on. You should make sure you know for sure how it's supposed to work (e.g. how does it communicate "not found"?) - or clarify with your tutor.

The pseudocode is:

```
foreach line of text
    read parent name and list of children
    tree.findChild(parent)
    if not found, create root node with name of parent
    foreach child
        create new node and add as child of parent
            (by assigning to left-child to the parent...
             ... or assigning to right-sibling of the previous child)
```

There are various ways you could rearrange that. For example you could construct an orphaned list of children:

```
 Node siblingList = new Node(first child)
 Node tail = head
 while(more children)
     newChild = new Node(next child)
     tail.rightSibling = newChild
     tail = newChild
```

... then attach that list of children to the appropriate parent.

```
 parent.leftChild = siblingList
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function with a signature like `<T extends Comparable<T>> TreeNode<T>  makeTree(T[] data)` In the method:

1. Create a new `TreeNode` to return
2. Set that nodes's `data` to be first element in the array.
3. Split the remaining elements into sibling and child groups
4. Call the `makeTree()` function on both the subgroups, provided they aren't empty
5. On the original node set the child and sibling to be the returned nodes
6. Set the returned node's parents to be the original node.
7. Finally return the original node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map<String, TreeNode<String>>` to store the nodes already created:

```
BufferedReader br = //.. this is your file reader

Map<String, TreeNode<String>> stringToTreeNode = new HashMap<>();
TreeNode<String> root = null;
String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] lineParts = line.split(" ");
    int oldSize = stringToTreeNode.size();
    TreeNode<String> parent = getOrCreateTreeNode(stringToTreeNode, lineParts[0]);
    if (oldSize != stringToTreeNode.size()) {
         // new parent node created

         // in the end the root is the only node without a parent
         root = parent;
    }
    if (lineParts.length > 1) {
        // create children
        TreeNode<String> child = getOrCreateTreeNode(stringToTreeNode, lineParts[1]);
        parent.leftChild = child;
        child.parent = parent; 
        for (int i = 2; i < lineParts.length; i++) {
            TreeNode<String> nextChild = getOrCreateTreeNode(stringToTreeNode, lineParts[i]);
            nextChild.parent = parent;
            child.rightSibling = nextChild;
            child = nextChild;
        }
    }
}
Tree<String> result = new Tree<String>(root);
```

Use this as helper function:

```
static TreeNode<String> getOrCreateTreeNode(Map<String, TreeNode<String>> map, String key) {
    TreeNode<String> result= map.get(key);
    if (result== null) {
         result = new TreeNode<>();
         result.data = key;
         map.put(key, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```